How to resolve android toolchain = Cannot execute /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17/bin/java to determine the version
I have installed the required flutter from the android toolchain and others, but when I run the flutter doctor, the error appears.
I have set JAVA_HOME in .zshrc and can see the java version and I have searched everything on stack youtube and others but it has not been resolved. How can I solve this, is there a step I missed or what, please let me know if you have the same problem and it has been solved.
Screenshoot

Enter in terminal those commands and add output to your question: which java, file /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17/bin/java, java -version, echo $JAVA_HOME

You should provide the result of running these command in terminal echo $JAVA_HOME and java --version.

When I enter the echo JAVA_HOME command, the output is not /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17/bin/java, because when I set it in .zshrc it was in another folder, and when I checked the path earlier, it was empty and had no contents.
